# Vue Components Best Practice - Quasar

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

Community!

I'm new to vue and got a question for best practice building vue components:

Im creating a Vue App for managing teams like football-, volleyball- or chessteams. A user can create a team (with name, color, type, ...) by using the team creation dialog.

In the Dialog there is a [stepper](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/stepper) to guide the user for creating a team. In each steps there are input or select fields with regex validation. Now i got multiple Options:

Option A: Creation of a single component including the stepper with inputs and selects. Outsourcing the validation regex in global config.

OR

Option B: Creation of the stepper as a Component, the input as a component and so on.

In my thoughts i would go with Option B cause i dont want multiple inputs doing the same and then i got the regex validation at one place where i need it. But on the otherhand i got a bit overhead which could "be complicated" cause i need to emit each value from the input up to the parent component (e.g. stepper).

What is here the best practice?

**Option A - Stepper**

```
 <q-stepper
          v-model='teamCreationStep'
          header-nav
          ref='stepper'
          color='primary'
          animated
          vertical
        >
          <q-step
            :name='1'
            title='Wähle deine Teamart aus'
            icon='sports_soccer'
            :done='teamCreationStep > 1'
          >
            <q-select filled v-model='this.tmpTeam.type' :options='options' label='Teamart'/>

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='teamCreationStep = 2' color='primary' label='Weiter' :disable='!this.tmpTeam.type'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>

          <q-step
            :name='2'
            title='Wähle deinen Teamnamen aus'
            icon='edit'
            :done='teamCreationStep > 2'
            :disable='!this.tmpTeam.type'
          >
            <q-input filled v-model='this.tmpTeam.name' label='Teamname'
                     hint="Min 3 - Max 10 Buchstaben"
                     lazy-rules
                     :rules="[val => val && /^[\w\d]{3,25}$/.test(val) || 'Mindestens 3 und Maximal 25 Zeichen']"
            />

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='teamCreationStep = 3' color='primary' label='Weiter'
                     :disable='!isTeamNameValid || !this.tmpTeam.name'/>
              <q-btn flat @click='teamCreationStep = 1' color='primary' label='Zurück' class='q-ml-sm'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>

          <q-step
            :name='3'
            title='Wähle dein Farbschema aus'
            icon='palette'
            :done='teamCreationStep > 3'
            :disable='!isTeamNameValid || !this.tmpTeam.name'
          >
            <q-input
              filled
              v-model='this.tmpTeam.color_primary'
              lazy-rules
              :rules="['anyColor']"
              class='my-input'
              label='Primär Farbe'
            >
              <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon name='colorize' class='cursor-pointer'>
                  <q-popup-proxy transition-show='scale' transition-hide='scale'>
                    <q-color v-model='this.tmpTeam.color_primary'/>
                  </q-popup-proxy>
                </q-icon>
              </template>
            </q-input>
            <q-input
              filled
              v-model='this.tmpTeam.color_secondary'
              lazy-rules
              :rules="['anyColor']"
              class='my-input'
              label='Sekundär Farbe'
            >
              <template v-slot:append>
                <q-icon name='colorize' class='cursor-pointer'>
                  <q-popup-proxy transition-show='scale' transition-hide='scale'>
                    <q-color v-model='this.tmpTeam.color_secondary'/>
                  </q-popup-proxy>
                </q-icon>
              </template>
            </q-input>

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='teamCreationStep = 4' color='primary' label='Weiter'
                     :disable='!this.tmpTeam.color_primary || !this.tmpTeam.color_secondary || !isTeamColorHexValid || !this.tmpTeam.name'/>
              <q-btn flat @click='teamCreationStep = 2' color='primary' label='Zurück' class='q-ml-sm'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>
        </q-stepper>
```

**Option B - Stepper:**

```
 <q-stepper
          v-model='currentStep'
          header-nav
          ref='stepper'
          color='primary'
          animated
          vertical
        >
          <q-step
            :name='1'
            :title='$t("chooseTeamType")'
            icon='sports_soccer'
            :done='currentStep > 1'
          >
            <team-type />

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='currentStep = 2' color='primary' :label='$t("continue")'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>

          <q-step
            :name='2'
            :title='$t("chooseTeamName")'
            icon='edit'
            :done='currentStep > 2'
          >
           <TeamName/>

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='currentStep = 3' color='primary' :label='$t("continue")'/>
              <q-btn flat @click='currentStep = 1' color='primary' :label='$t("back")' class='q-ml-sm'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>

          <q-step
            :name='3'
            :title='$t("chooseTeamColor")'
            icon='palette'
            :done='currentStep > 3'
          >
            <TeamColor/>

            <TeamColor/>

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='currentStep = 4' color='primary' :label='$t("continue")' />
              <q-btn flat @click='currentStep = 2' color='primary' :label='$t("back")' class='q-ml-sm'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>

          <q-step
            :name='4'
            :title='$t("chooseTeamLogo")'
            icon='image'
            :done='currentStep > 4'
          >

            <TeamLogo/>

            <q-stepper-navigation>
              <q-btn @click='currentStep = 5' color='primary' :label='$t("continue")'/>
              <q-btn flat @click='currentStep = 3' color='primary' :label='$t("back")' class='q-ml-sm'/>
            </q-stepper-navigation>
          </q-step>
        </q-stepper>
```

**OPTION B: Input**

```
<template>
  <q-input
    filled
    v-model="teamName"
    :label="$t('teamName')"
    :rules="[val => val && /^[\w\d]{3,25}$/.test(val) || $t('error_teamNameRestriction') ]"
    counter
    :maxlength="25"
    :autofocus="true">
  </q-input>
</template>
```

[image: Option B File Structure]